# How to fill color in png image or icon with css only?

Tags: png

I have tried css filters.

But not working. Is there any way to fill color in `png icon` with css only.

**Refrence image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap it in a div with a background color set, and if the png has transparency the background color will appear. However, the image you linked to is a jpg, not a png.